# Triggers on specific time in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to execute a code at 7.00 PM daily in Google Sheets. I created trigger but it is executing at 7.58 PM daily.

```
function Work_Flow_Trigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("Work_Flow")
            .timeBased()
            .atHour(19)
            .nearMinute(00)
            .everyDays(1)
            .create();
}
```

Comment: Check the timezone of your script using `Logger.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());`, it might be 1 hour ahead of what you're expecting.

Comment: HI @ross Thanks for the reply. I have checked timezone with your script. It is matching with our local timezone. So it is not issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nearMinute() is not exact, it's plus/minus 15 minutes (please refer to API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearMinute(Integer)).

If you need to be more precise you have to use everyMinutes(1) and add a code to run target function once you reach desired point in time.

Comment: Thanks @mtelis. So if I give .atHour(19) and .nearMinute(15) then will it execute somewhere between 7.00 to 7.30? I guess everyMinutes(1)  will have performance issue or unnecessary call of script although I handle it in code.

There should be someway to schedule a job at specific time?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no direct way to schedule a job at precise time. If you don't want your function called every minute for hours you can schedule nearMinute() for say, 20 minutes prior to desired time and then start 1-minute polls.

Comment: Plus/minus 15 mins from 7pm would create a trigger between 6:45pm and 7:15pm. OP said their trigger was created for 7:58pm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Work_Flow_Trigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("Work_Flow")
            .timeBased()
            .atHour(18)
            .nearMinute(02)
            .everyDays(1)
            .create();
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I shall try and confirm. May I know the reason for it?

Comment: @SaiKrishna I am guessing the idea is if it is running an hour ahead, to change the atHour by an hour less.